# How long is a Canadian transit visa valid for once it has been issued?

Tags: canada, transit-visas, vancouver

How long is a Canadian transit visa valid for once it has been issued? We plan to travel to Mexico from the Philippines via Vancouver. We don't plan to leave the airport. Also, how soon should we apply for the transit visa before we leave the Philippines, 2 or 3 months in advance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

- How long is a Canadian transit visa valid for once it has been issued?

The validity period of the Canadian transit visa will reflect the travel plans you provide when you apply.

> A transit visa is an official document stamped in your passport. It shows that you meet the requirements to transit through a Canadian airport. It can be v[alid for one or two entries, depending on your travel plans](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/transit/eligibility.html). You must use your visa before it expires.

- How soon should we apply for the transit visa before we leave?

If you're eligible to [use the online tool](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/transit/apply.html), you can apply for the transit visa 30-45 days in advance of your departure. If you're sending the application by mail, allow for 2-3 months. You can also [check processing times](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=068&_ga=2.110812417.523595586.1529332973-1420682779.1528551134) specific to your location.

> We calculate processing times from the day we receive an application to the day it makes a decision on the application.
>
> When estimating how long you will wait to receive a temporary visa, you must also take into account up to 10 days of transit or delivery time on top of our processing time. The time your application will spend travelling to and from IRCC will vary depending on where you live.